# InProc Session State not working

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, inproc

Anyone have any ideas why a servers InProc session state would not be working?  Is there a manual reset for it, or a way to check?

Thanks

Session mode is InProc, timeout is 25 minutes.

At this time I'm unsure if the Session object is null, or if the session object is empty and cannot be accessed.

I'm thinking it could be a cookie issue, or it could be that Application_Start doesn't fire properly.  What else could it be? IIS settings?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but I hope this will help someone.
Mine didn't work and I found out that I needed to add httpModules to web.config file.

**Web.config:**

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"
 sqlConnectionString="YourConnectionString">
</sessionState>

<httpModules>
   <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
</httpModules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't setting Session variables in your Application_Start event.  That is what the Session_Start is for.

Also, is your application pre-compiled?  Check this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937095) if so.

**Reset Options:**

- Run [IISReset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566/what-does-an-iisreset-do/23584#23584)
- Restart the World Wide Web
  Publishing(W3SVC) service.
- Manually recycle the App Pool in IIS

Comment: Post some code, what you are stating in your question doesn't sound right