# Does Application_Start event in global.asax fires when code is re-published?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

Does the Application_Start in global.asax called when the new published code is kept in IIS web root for the project,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Application_Start` triggers everytime the application pool is recycled which normally happens when you update some of the files in the bin folder or web.config. So if you republish your site and update some of those files IIS will unload the application and `Application_Start` will fire next time a request comes in.

Comment: So can we a say that `Application_Start` triggers on a first request?

Comment: @SangramNandkhile  Correct, running the debugger, locally or remotely, verifies Application_Start is called the first time application is accessed after application pool is recycled (I am sure you've found your answer by now. Response is also for future readers).

Comment: The application pool is NOT recycled when you update the files. but the AppDomain is reloaded. `Application_Start` does fire, but please remove the confusing statement about App pool recycle. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64671746/56621

Answer (score 0):

If your Global.asax Application_Start code is not firing on a IIS published web:

Try changing your application AppPool to ASP.NET v4.0 Classic.
Stop the AppPool
Start the AppPool
Recycle the AppPool.

Check if it works.