# IIS rewriteMaps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, web-config

I have problem with `rewriteMaps` in `Web.config`. My `rewriteMaps` section is in separate file, something like this `configSource="webConfigRules\rule1.config"`. It's working, but only for static rules. I would like to make changes and refresh whole `rewriteMaps` section without server restart. 
It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS will recycle the application pool when your web.config file changes but not for the rewrite rules file. You can either manually recycle the app pool or force a recycle using another method. This answer gives a good explanation if you need more information [Does any change in any file inside bin folder cause application recycle in ASP.NET web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802812/does-any-change-in-any-file-inside-bin-folder-cause-application-recycle-in-asp-n#9803159)