# Ajax PUT request: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException : virtual application is shutting down

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf, iis

So when I"m doing an ajax request to `PUT` onto the server I periodically get the exception thrown:

```
System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException
```

Whenever I refresh the page and do the `PUT` request for the first time, I always gets this error. If I send the same request again immediately with the same content, it works. Future requests sometimes get this error again. When the page first loads many `GET` requests are performed and they never face this problem.

The Ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: "PUT",
        data: contents,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: settings.success,
        error: settings.error
    });
```

The C# function called is

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "users/{userName}/projects/{projectName}/{*fileName}", Method = "PUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string PutFile(string userName, string projectName, string fileName, Stream fileContents);
```

From the event viewer logs here is the error detailed:

```
    WebHost failed to process a request.

    Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/45004378

    Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: Request to the service at '~/' cannot be dispatched because the virtual application at '/bb' is shutting down. 
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Request to the service at '~/' cannot be dispatched because the virtual application at '/bb' is shutting down.
```

I've tried to disable application recycle by following this link: https://serverfault.com/questions/333907/what-should-i-do-to-make-sure-that-iis-does-not-recycle-my-application

But it didn't help at all. What could be some possible reasons that my application is shutting down when I make the requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that I was sending one PUT request too quickly after another. I added a small delay of 250ms between them and this error is no longer an issue.

Edit: The need for the delay got too annoying, so I looked into it more. The reason for my problems was because I was writing to the bin folder of the web app.

[Does any change in any file inside bin folder cause application recycle in ASP.NET web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802812/does-any-change-in-any-file-inside-bin-folder-cause-application-recycle-in-asp-n)

Comment: Thanks for your research, saved me quite some time.