# Stop app pool recycling on changes to directories

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, iis

We are seeing occasionally that our app pool restarts. This should not be happening and the log file tells us:

```
_shutDownMessage=CONFIG change
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
Overwhelming Change Notification in 
Change Notification for critical directories.
Overwhelming Change Notification in App_LocalResources
Change Notification for critical directories.
Overwhelming Change Notification in App_Browsers
Change Notification for critical directories.
Overwhelming Change Notification in App_Code
Change Notification for critical directories.
Overwhelming Change Notification in App_WebReferences
Change Notification for critical directories.
Overwhelming Change Notification in App_GlobalResources
```

We do not use any of these directories and looking at the directory structure these directories do not exist for the application.

We do not have any anti-virus apps running and as this is a server app, no one will be looking at the web application directories.

As I am stumped why this happens occasionally I was wondering if there is a way I can debug further to find out what is causing this or if I can disable app pool restarts for the above 'Overwhelming Change Notification...' reason above?

Comment: None of the directories exist?  Have you made sure they aren't just hidden, go to view options on file explorer and click "show hidden files and folders".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802812/does-any-change-in-any-file-inside-bin-folder-cause-application-recycle-in-asp-n

The reasons the app pool could be recycling are in there.   I suspect the above error you are seeing is some sort of permission change that triggered all the affected child folders change event.

Comment: A scenario that happened to me once.  I had code on my site that would create folders for user uploads and modify their permissions for them as we used NTLM authentication.

The site was resetting about once every 15 minutes, and couldn't figure out.  Turns out it was Active Directory Group Policy which was set to do a gpupdate every 15 minutes.  My code was removing  permission that Group Policy had set so when gpupdate ran and put them back (being externally accessed) the app pool would reset.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. There are no folder hidden but you mentioned something interesting. We do upload files to the server that get unzipped and then processed. I am checking with our IT admins to see if Active Directory Group Policy could be an issue. I'll let you know in a bit.

Comment: Just checked with IT and they are adamant that the Virtual machines that they are providing use the basic Active Directory settings so there should not be any changes made to web directories. Any ideas on where to look now? I wonder if I can check on the VM to see some windows log that can tell me what happened?

Comment: Hi, our apps root directory has many sub folders which we upload to and create subfolders. I read somewhere that this could cause app pool recycle. Our app has been designed for years like this so I doubt this is the issue as would have seen the problem but I thought I would mention it.

Comment: As a test, you could try moving all of your directories to another folder (outside of the site's main iis directory).  Then use Virtual Directories inside IIS to link to them.  That way they will no longer be monitored by IIS.  Which is technically how upload folders should be set up anyways.  They should reside on another drive or at the least, out of the site directory.  You can go to settings on a virtual directory and enter the account credentials that has the needed access to the folders, or grant IIS_IUSR access to the new folders.

Comment: Did you ever got solution for your problem, my problem is exactly the same you had. And I am a bit reluctant to go with solution suggested in last comment

Comment: No there was no resolution. I have always put it down to virus scans or some sort of group policies. It has been really quiet and we have not heard of any other issues but on my local machine I did see the problem happening with the virus scanner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I disable overwhelming change notifications in IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373452/can-i-disable-overwhelming-change-notifications-in-iis)