# Can I disable overwhelming change notifications in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am getting occasionally the following events which causes an application pool to be recycled:

```
_shutDownMessage=CONFIG change
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
Overwhelming Change Notification in 
Change Notification for critical directories.
Overwhelming Change Notification in App_LocalResources
Change Notification for critical directories.
Overwhelming Change Notification in App_Browsers
Change Notification for critical directories.
Overwhelming Change Notification in App_Code
Change Notification for critical directories.
Overwhelming Change Notification in App_WebReferences
Change Notification for critical directories.
Overwhelming Change Notification in App_GlobalResources
```

Is there a way I can prevent these changes from recycling the app pool?

We are about to go live in production in a few days, so I need a quick solution for now until we have time later to resolve what is causing this.

Comment: What OS version, IIS version, and .NET version are you using?

Comment: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, IIS 6+ (mostly IIS 7) and .net 4.

Comment: Okay... if it was .NET 2.0, then [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913297/en-us) or [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920970) might have helped. But I doubt they apply in this scenario.

Comment: Are you doing any changes to files in those directories? Use Process Monitor (from Sysinternals) and check what process is causing the notifications.

Comment: I have checked all those directories and our app is not changing any of them. This is why I think it is something outside of our app that is doing the changes. There is no anti virus running so it is not that. I just need a way to turn off the check for now.

Answer (score 6):

This can be caused by different FCN modes in ASP.Net and a particular MS bug also makes this occur. FCN (file change notification) is controlled both at the ASP.Net level and at the IIS level.

You can change the fcnMode in your web.config to monitor much less, we apply the "Single" model to most of our websites now especially when running on Azure due to it's network based file storage. However, to change the IIS file change watching is a different story.

Here's a details post about FCN and it's different modes: http://shazwazza.com/post/all-about-aspnet-file-change-notification-fcn/

Here's the MS hotfix for the IIS FCN issue (which is optional for some insane reason): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/911272

This talks about how to disable IIS's FCN if you have access to do that: http://imageresizing.net/docs/fcnmode

It's also worth noting that changing the fcnMode to Single in the web.config will have no affect on any IIS virtual folders, fcn can only be disabled entirely to have any affect on virtual folders.