# C# CompilerParameters.OutputAssembly causes application to restart

Tags: c#, csharpcodeprovider

I am developing an ASP.Net C# application, in which users may compile piece of code on the fly. I'm using CSharpCodeProvider in this case.

The problem that I just encountered, was that somehow the CompilerParameter.OutputAssembly causes the application to restart (I checked that Application_Start() is called after compilation). Once I put it on comment, the compilation works like charm with no restarting occurs.

I'm wondering if this case is true, or if I'm missing a concept somewhere. What I understood from
CompilerParameter.OutputAssembly is that it makes the assembly to be outputted into a specified file. Is it normal for the application to restart?

Comment: Is it possible that this is caused by an uncaught exception?

Comment: it's already answered by @Ondrej :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're putting this assembly into bin folder of your web application then yes - IIS actively watches bin directory of your web application & forces restart when you add or update .dll file in bin folder.

For complete list check out:
[Does any change in any file inside bin folder cause application recycle in ASP.NET web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802812/does-any-change-in-any-file-inside-bin-folder-cause-application-recycle-in-asp-n)