# Application is shutting down. Reason: Configuration changed - any reason

Tags: asp.net, iis, appdomain, health-monitoring, recycle

I'm encountering an app domain recycle, once in a a couple of weeks on my live environment. I've added healthMonitoring configuration to the web.config in order to get the reason for the application restart. When this recycling happened I got
"**Application is shutting down. Reason: Configuration changed**" - event id 50004

I've checked the files under the root path and non of them was changed - at least according to the modified date property.
Also non of the machines.config nor the applicationHost.config were changed.

Any idea how can I tackle this and understand what exactly cause this configuration changed event?
Maybe which file was changed or which process caused the configuration change...

Notice that I've checked that my application isn't changing any file on run-time.
Also I've checked with my IT guy and it seems that no backup or Anti-Virus is running on this root.

Any idea?

Comment: A change to **any** file in the /bin folder or sub-folders will cause a recycle.  [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802812/does-any-change-in-any-file-inside-bin-folder-cause-application-recycle-in-asp-n).  That is the first place I would look.

Comment: Yes I know, but non of my files/folders under the root were changed...

Comment: You can enable file and object access auditing for the folder. In the properties page for a folder, choose Security, Advanced, then the Auditing tab.