# Is there any IIS caching for Active Directory?

Tags: iis, active-directory, ldap

Suppose I have the following two domains:

1. Domain A (Server with AD configured)
2. Domain B (Server with AD configured)

I have another server named "C" which refer to Domain A DNS and using user in its domain.

Each time I change the trust setting between domain A and domain B (using "Active Directory Domains and Trusts"), and do IIS reset on my server(C) I can see the changes affects. On the other hand, If I change the trust setting between domain A and domain B and DON'T preform IIS reset on my server(C) I can't see the change affects.

**Note** : I'm using C# in my server C in order to preform LDAP queries using `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher`.

How is the IIS reset I preform on my server (C) allows me to see my **updated** domain A Active Directory trust data?

Is there any cache being used by the IIS which cleans up when restarted?

***One more thing***, I tried to disable the "**Enable cache**" and the "**Enable kernel cache**" settings on my server C via IIS but yet each change setting of the trust between A and B applies on my server only after I restart my IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer.

When you preform iisreset, the World Wide Web Publishing Service (w3svc) is stopped and restarted causing the cache to be deleted.

Possibly there is a cache information stored in http.sys which delivers the request internally without to communicate with the domain server again (for performance issues).

Here are some articles I found which might help for who's interested in this subject too:

1. [What does an IISReset do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566/what-does-an-iisreset-do)
2. http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture#WWW
3. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129
4. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sudeepg/archive/2007/11/16/working-with-http-sys-or-kernel-mode-caching-in-internet-information-services-6-0.aspx

Also you can read the following two articles to better understand how to trace the http.sys file:

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2007/01/18/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-1-capturing-a-trace.aspx
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2007/01/25/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-2-anatomy-of-an-event.aspx